# Cite working paper

Tags: bibtex, citing, mendeley

I am exporting the `.bib` file from Mendeley and use it in my bibliography. However, working papers only appear with author names and paper title. They miss the working paper series and paper number. The paper number does not even get transferred to the `.bib` file, although is is entered in Mendeley at the right spot, see attached image.

```
@unpublished{Brandts2017,
address = {Center for Economic Studies {\&} Ifo Institute},
author = {Brandts, Jordi and Riedl, Arno},
file = {:Users/Desktop/Mendeley Papers/SSRN-id2731096.pdf:pdf},
institution = {CESIfo},
keywords = {CESifo Working Paper no. 5694,competition,cooperation,experiments},
series = {CESIfo Working Paper},
title = {{Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation}},
year = {2017}
}
```

Using `\bibliographystyle{chicago}` or `\bibliographystyle{apa}` followed by `\bibliography{library}` then gives

Brandts, J. and A. Riedl (2017). Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation.

But what I need is:

Brandts, J. and A. Riedl (2017). Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation. CESIfo Working Paper No. 5694.

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

I updated the entry in Mendeley, see image.

In the `.bib` this gives:

```
@techreport{Brandts2017,
address = {Munich},
author = {Brandts, Jordi and Riedl, Arno},
file = {:Users/Desktop/Mendeley Papers/SSRN-id2731096.pdf:pdf},
institution = {Center for Economic Studies {\&} Ifo Institute},
keywords = {CESifo Working Paper no. 5694,competition,cooperation,experiments},
series = {CESIfo Working Paper},
title = {{Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation}},
year = {2017}
}
```

In the pdf this still gives:

Brandts, J. and Riedl, A. (2017). Market Interaction and Efficient Coop- eration. Technical report, Center for Economic Studies & Ifo Institute, Munich.

What I still need is the "technical report" to dissapear, and the paper number needs to be shown.

[image]

Comment: Which entry type do you employ for this entry? Is it `@techreport`? If not, what else?

Comment: It is `@unpublished`.

Comment: Incidentally, I have some strong doubts that `address = {Center for Economic Studies {\&} Ifo Institute},` is correct. Isn't that the information for the `institution` rather than for the address?

Comment: Well, there you have it: For working papers in a working paper series, you should be using the entry type `@techreport`, not `@unpublished`.

Comment: If I use `@techreport` what I get is: Brandts, J. and A. Riedl (2017): “Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation,” Tech. rep., CESIfo, Center for Economic Studies & Ifo Institute.

Comment: Yes, but without address and instead `institution = {Center for Economic Studies {\&} Ifo Institute},` I still get the same result.

Comment: What I told you that the information provided by Mendeley for the `address` field was incorrect. I did *not* tell you not to use the `address` field. Hint: CESIfo is based in Munich, not in "Center for Economic Studies {\&} Ifo Institute"...

Comment: The problem seems to be that Mendeley does not generate the `type` and `number` field. Unfortunately, I am stuck with Mendeley as I need pdfs and bibliography combined. I contacted them.

Comment: Assuming you can get Mendeley generate a bib file, can you edit the bib file by hand to add the `type` and `number` fields? (Of course, you should do such hand-editing only at the very end of the process of writing the paper.)

Comment: I did that, but it's at best a short-term solution. Hope I can get the right `bib` file automatically rather than by hand.

Comment: It's good that you contacted Mendeley, since the `type` and `number` fields are definitely standard for entries of type `@techreport`, for all bibliography styles I'm familiar with.

Comment: Their response (for those Mendeley users, I know many): "Inconsistencies when exporting/importing from a Mendeley library into another file format (Bibtex)  - (vice-versa) is a known issue that has been reported already to our Development Team. However they did not provide a specific time frame on when can this be fixed but it is one of the issues that are included in their priority pipeline. For now, the only workaround is to manually edit/correct the entries in the Bibtex file."

Comment: Well, you can't say you didn't try! And I can't say that their non-committal response comes as a surprise. As I wrote in another comment, I gave up on Mendeley years ago, and I've never regretted my decision. Your recent experience, if anything, is a confirmation that made the right choice, long ago.

Answer (score 10):

You should be using the `@techreport` entry type for the paper at hand. In the solution below, note that I added the `type` field. If this field not provided, it defaults to "Technical Report", whereas here it should quite obviously be "Working Paper". You also need to furnish a `number` field, for the number of the working paper.

The field that's currently labelled "address" is wrong -- that's the `institution`. For the `address` field, you should definitely use "Munich", not "Center for Economic Studies \& Ifo Institute". (Just because some pieces of information are provided by Mendeley doesn't mean that you're absolved from checking each and every entry carefully for errors and omissions...)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@techreport{brandts-riedl:2017,
address = {Munich},
author  = {Brandts, Jordi and Riedl, Arno},
institution = {Center for Economic Studies \& Ifo Institute},
keywords= {CESifo Working Paper no. 5694, competition,cooperation,experiments},
series  = {CESIfo Working Paper},
type    = {Working Paper},
number  = {5694},
title   = {Market Interaction and Efficient Cooperation},
year    = {2017},
xmonth  = jul,
xnote   = {(Initial version: Jan. 2016)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I missing `type` in my `.bib` file. Any idea how to add this from Mendeley? Thanks.

Comment: @360McTwist - Mendeley-related questions are off-topic on TeX.SE; they should be communicated to Mendeley help site. FWIW, I tried to use Mendeley several years ago, and found it to be so buggy and error-ridden that I quickly gave up on it. I've never regretted this decision.